# Unable to install Scipy on AWS Linux

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, scipy

Trying to install bunch of packages - specifically **scipy** - on latest AWS Linux box. It is a t2.large machine.

**Python 2.7.12** and **pip 6.1.1 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)** are installed. (Not upgrading **pip** as it totally screwed things up.)

I have run the following commands.

```
sudo yum install -y freetype-devel libpng-devel gcc-c++ python27-devel python27-matplotlib atlas-sse3-devel lapack-devel atlas-devel    
sudo yum groupinstall 'Development Tools'
sudo yum install atlas-sse3-devel lapack-devel
sudo pip install numpy
sudo pip install pandas
sudo pip install scipy
```

Getting following error -

```
You are using pip version 6.1.1, however version 9.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
Collecting scipy
  Using cached scipy-0.19.0.zip
Installing collected packages: scipy
  Running setup.py install for scipy
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python2.7 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-YoX5be/scipy/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-NjTyw2-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:

Note: if you need reliable uninstall behavior, then install
with pip instead of using `setup.py install`:

  - `pip install .`       (from a git repo or downloaded source
                           release)
  - `pip install scipy`   (last SciPy release on PyPI)


lapack_opt_info:
lapack_mkl_info:
mkl_info:
  libraries mkl,vml,guide not found in ['/usr/local/lib64', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib64', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/']
  NOT AVAILABLE

  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_threads_info:
Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
  libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/local/lib64
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib64
  libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib64/atlas-sse3
numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info
Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
customize Gnu95FCompiler
Found executable /usr/bin/gfortran
customize Gnu95FCompiler
customize Gnu95FCompiler using config
compiling '_configtest.c':

/* This file is generated from numpy/distutils/system_info.py */
void ATL_buildinfo(void);
int main(void) {
  ATL_buildinfo();
  return 0;
}

C compiler: gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC

compile options: '-c'
gcc: _configtest.c
gcc -pthread _configtest.o -L/usr/lib64/atlas-sse3 -lptf77blas -lptcblas -latlas -o _configtest
ATLAS version 3.8.4 built by mockbuild on Sat Jul  7 07:28:07 UTC 2012:
   UNAME    : Linux gobi-build-31003.sea31.amazon.com 2.6.18-164.el5az00 #1 SMP Tue Sep 15 14:19:07 EDT 2009 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
   INSTFLG  : -1 0 -a 1
   ARCHDEFS : -DATL_OS_Linux -DATL_ARCH_Core2 -DATL_CPUMHZ=2333 -DATL_SSE2 -DATL_SSE1 -DATL_USE64BITS -DATL_GAS_x8664
   F2CDEFS  : -DAdd_ -DF77_INTEGER=int -DStringSunStyle
   CACHEEDGE: 212992
   F77      : gfortran, version GNU Fortran (GCC) 4.4.6 20110731 (Red Hat 4.4.6-3)
   F77FLAGS : -O -g -Wa,--noexecstack -fPIC -m64
   SMC      : gcc, version gcc (GCC) 4.4.6 20110731 (Red Hat 4.4.6-3)
   SMCFLAGS : -fomit-frame-pointer -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -O2 -g -Wa,--noexecstack -fPIC -m64
   SKC      : gcc, version gcc (GCC) 4.4.6 20110731 (Red Hat 4.4.6-3)
   SKCFLAGS : -fomit-frame-pointer -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -O2 -g -Wa,--noexecstack -fPIC -m64
success!
removing: _configtest.c _configtest.o _configtest
Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
  FOUND:
    libraries = ['lapack', 'ptf77blas', 'ptcblas', 'atlas']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/lib64/atlas-sse3']
    language = f77
    define_macros = [('ATLAS_INFO', '"\\"3.8.4\\""')]
    include_dirs = ['/usr/include']

  FOUND:
    libraries = ['lapack', 'ptf77blas', 'ptcblas', 'atlas']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/lib64/atlas-sse3']
    language = f77
    define_macros = [('ATLAS_INFO', '"\\"3.8.4\\""')]
    include_dirs = ['/usr/include']

Running from scipy source directory.
/usr/lib64/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:574: UserWarning: Specified path /usr/lib64/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/__init__.pyc/include/python2.7 is invalid.
  warnings.warn('Specified path %s is invalid.' % d)
/usr/lib64/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:574: UserWarning: Specified path /usr/local/include/python2.7 is invalid.
  warnings.warn('Specified path %s is invalid.' % d)
non-existing path in 'scipy/integrate': 'quadpack.h'
ATLAS version: 3.8.4
Splitting linalg.interpolative Fortran source files
blas_opt_info:
blas_mkl_info:
  libraries mkl,vml,guide not found in ['/usr/local/lib64', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib64', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/']
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_blas_threads_info:
Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
  FOUND:
    libraries = ['ptf77blas', 'ptcblas', 'atlas']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/lib64/atlas-sse3']
    language = c
    define_macros = [('ATLAS_INFO', '"\\"3.8.4\\""')]
    include_dirs = ['/usr/include']

  FOUND:
    libraries = ['ptf77blas', 'ptcblas', 'atlas']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/lib64/atlas-sse3']
    language = c
    define_macros = [('ATLAS_INFO', '"\\"3.8.4\\""')]
    include_dirs = ['/usr/include']

non-existing path in 'scipy/sparse': 'sparsetools/sparsetools_impl.h'
non-existing path in 'scipy/sparse': 'sparsetools/bsr_impl.h'
non-existing path in 'scipy/sparse': 'sparsetools/csc_impl.h'
non-existing path in 'scipy/sparse': 'sparsetools/csr_impl.h'
non-existing path in 'scipy/sparse': 'sparsetools/other_impl.h'
running install
running build
running config_cc
unifing config_cc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --compiler options
running config_fc
unifing config_fc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --fcompiler options
running build_src
build_src
building py_modules sources
creating build
creating build/src.linux-x86_64-2.7
creating build/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/scipy
building library "dfftpack" sources
building library "fftpack" sources
building library "mach" sources
building library "quadpack" sources
building library "odepack" sources
building library "dop" sources
building library "fitpack" sources
building library "fwrappers" sources
building library "odrpack" sources
building library "minpack" sources
building library "rootfind" sources
building library "superlu_src" sources
building library "arpack_scipy" sources
building library "sc_c_misc" sources
building library "sc_cephes" sources
building library "sc_mach" sources
building library "sc_amos" sources
building library "sc_cdf" sources
building library "sc_specfun" sources
building library "statlib" sources
building extension "scipy.cluster._vq" sources
building extension "scipy.cluster._hierarchy" sources
building extension "scipy.fftpack._fftpack" sources
creating build/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/scipy/fftpack
creating build/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/scipy/fftpack/src
conv_template:> build/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/scipy/fftpack/src/dct.c
conv_template:> build/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/scipy/fftpack/src/dst.c
f2py options: []
f2py: scipy/fftpack/fftpack.pyf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/tmp/pip-build-YoX5be/scipy/setup.py", line 416, in <module>
    setup_package()
  File "/tmp/pip-build-YoX5be/scipy/setup.py", line 412, in setup_package
    setup(**metadata)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/distutils/core.py", line 186, in setup
    return old_setup(**new_attr)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 151, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/distutils/command/install.py", line 57, in run
    r = self.setuptools_run()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/distutils/command/install.py", line 31, in setuptools_run
    return old_install_mod._install.run(self)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/distutils/command/install.py", line 604, in run
    self.run_command('build')
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 326, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/distutils/command/build.py", line 37, in run
    old_build.run(self)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/distutils/command/build.py", line 127, in run
    self.run_command(cmd_name)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 326, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 152, in run
    self.build_sources()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 169, in build_sources
    self.build_extension_sources(ext)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 334, in build_extension_sources
    sources = self.f2py_sources(sources, ext)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 571, in f2py_sources
    import numpy.f2py
ImportError: No module named f2py

----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python2.7 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-YoX5be/scipy/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-NjTyw2-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-YoX5be/scipy
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why, but it looks like when `numpy` was installed it didn't install `f2py` properly. `f2py` is maintained by `numpy` as far as I know, and it looks like it's trying to access `numpy.f2py` in the python installer.

Try `sudo yum install -y numpy-f2py`, and then `pip install scipy`.

P.S. If you're looking for `numpy`, `scipy`, `pandas`, `sklearn`, and other useful libraries, consider installing/using Anaconda instead. The Anaconda installer probably takes care of this problem one way or another, because I've never had any problems with it.

Comment: Thanks for the tip... did the `numpy-f2py` install using yum. Also realised there is a `python27-scipy` package available as a yum package. Installed that (`sudo yum install -y python27-scipy`) instead of using pip. It worked!